# Error c3892 iterator issue in VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, stl

I am migrating a Visual Studio 2008 VC++ project to Visual Studio 2013. I am getting error C3892 when migrating one of my projects. Here is some sample code which reproduces the problem:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    struct student
    {
        int id;
        int marks;
        bool changed;

        bool operator < (const student& refParam) const
        {
            return false ;
        }
        student(int a,int b)
        {
            id=a;
            marks=b;
            changed=true;
        }
    };

    student x(10,500),y(15,600);
    std::multiset<student> myset;
    myset.insert(x);
    myset.insert(y);
    std::multiset<student>::reverse_iterator iter;
    for (iter=myset.rbegin(); iter != myset.rend(); ++iter)
    {
        std::cout<<iter->id<<"\n";
        std::cout<<iter->marks<<"\n";
        std::cout<<iter->changed<<"\n";
        iter->changed=false;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Trying to compile the above throws an error:

```
error C3892: 'std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base>::operator ->' : you cannot assign to a variable that is const
```

However, the same code compiles without error in Visual Studio 2008. Should I change the value in my project?

Comment: That `operator <` is not compliant whatsoever with the strict weak order requirements of `std::set`. Implement one that does something besides always returning `false`. And the iterator for `set` changed in C++11 to refer to const elements rather than non-const, which is causing your error.

Comment: @WhozCraig `return std::tie(id, mark, changed) < std::tie(refParam.id, refParam.mark, refParam.changed)` is not the most efficient way, but it's good enough I suppose.

Comment: @Joker_vD if I needed to order on all three, I wouldn't do it any other way. `std::tie` is the cats whiskers for that.

Comment: @WhozCraig Well, I never really wanted to learn if `a==b` should be equivalent to `(!(a<b)) && (!(b<a))`, so I always write (arbitrary) strict total orders for `operator<`.

Comment: @Joker_vD Ha. interesting. I actually prefer it. Maybe its a in-my-head thing, but strict ordering has always played nice in my grey-matter.

Answer (score 1):

All multiset iterators in C++ 11 point to a const elements. If you want to modify element you need to remove it and insert a new one.
As a hack you may declare struct variable as mutable (not recommended). Do it only if you are sure what you are doing

```
mutable bool changed;
```

Also you should write a proper operator <.

Comment: Instead of using a `mutable` hack, change your set to a map and put "changed" in the value part where it's safe to mutate.

Answer (score -2):

As per the C++11 standard, implemented in VS2010 onward, we cannot change the elements in a set or multiset. By default the iterator references a constant element. If we want to change the elements in a set or multiset, we have to do explicit type casting.

In the above code `iter->changed=false` throws a C3892 error, but if we change the statement to

```
const_cast<student&>(*item).changed=false;
```

instead, it will compile without any errors.

Comment: It's dangerous to change a set member. (Particularly if this would put it "out of order" in the set.)

Comment: While this will **compile**, it's not right. In fact, I'm pretty sure it's undefined behavior. See http://ideone.com/RGKdqw for a possible consequence.